# Why is my AWS Lambda function using the wrong URL to communicate with OpenSearch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, opensearch

I have a lambda function which needs to communicate with an AWS OpenSearch domain.

The domain is contained within a VPC, and the lambda function has been placed within the same VPC and subnet.

The VPC contains has an internet gateway and a proxy server, and the Opensearch Domain has a url accessible from outside the VPC in addition to its automatically-generated URL.

When the lambda function attempts to connect to the Opensearch API, it times out. Weirdly, however, it shows that it's attempting to access the wrong URL. Regardless of whether I use the public-facing URL or the in-VPC url beginning with 'https://vpc-{my-vpc-name}", it shows that it timed out attempting to contact 'https://search-{my-vpc-name}'

I believe that the relevant code is in here:

```
RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(HttpHost.create({my-url-here}))
    .setHttpClientConfigCallback(httpAsyncClientBuilder -> httpAsyncClientBuilder.addInterceptorLast(interceptor));
restClient = new RestHighLevelClient(builder);
```

I really don't understand why it would use the modified (and non-existent) URL regardless of what it's told to use. Could this be a DNS issue of some sort, or should I be looking more at how OpenSearch and the AWS Java library work?

Comment: Do a `System.out.println` of `restClient.getUrl` or whatever the correct way would be to get the URL - does the client have the appropriate URL? Something must be changing it in your code somewhere. Do you have a minimal example? How are you creating the URL? What action are you trying to perform? We need more information.

Comment: did you whitelist lambda security group in inbound rules of SG of Opensearch?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are missing the correct Security Group configurations, see below a CDK snippet to setup these Security Groups

```
        SecurityGroup openSearchSecurityGroup = SecurityGroup.Builder.create(this, id + "sg-search")
            .vpc(vpc)
            .build();

    SecurityGroup lambdaSecurityGroup = SecurityGroup.Builder.create(this, id + "sg-lambda")
            .vpc(vpc)
            .build();

    lambdaSecurityGroup.addEgressRule(openSearchSecurityGroup, Port.tcp(443));
    openSearchSecurityGroup.addIngressRule(lambdaSecurityGroup, Port.tcp(443));
```